# Two ethernet connects how can I set the default one?

Tags: windows-8, home-networking, connection, ethernet, isp

I have Two ethernet cards / Connections

How can I tell windows to set Eth1 as default so web,steaming all the normal stuff uses this connection?

I have set bittorrent up correctly to use the other connection
but after a restart windows starts to use the bittorrent one. And if I change bittorrent to use the other one It just does the very same thing on the next reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections.

[Alt to Show Menu Bar.]

Navigate Advanced > Advanced Settings.

Change priority to an adapter by moving it up in the Connections list.

Click OK.